# Trouble linking mongod to archive files

Tags: c++, mongodb, gcc, scons

I have been trying to link **mongod** to archive files instead of using shared libraries. Currently, I have no problem in linking **mongod** to shared libraries (.so files) and everything works fine. However, things are a bit different with static libraries and archive files built externally.

Here is what I am basically trying to do. I have two .a files, say *lib1.a* and *lib2.a*, and I am using make to generate these files. What I am trying to do is linking these two archive files statically to **mongod** by modifying the **SCons** build script, the one located in mongo/src/db. What I am expected to see is something like this:

g++ -o build/linux2/normal/mongo/mongod ........ somapath/lib1.a somepath/lib2.a ..... -lpthread -lrt

As I am not familiar with SCons, it has been a hassle for me to change it so far. Anyone has any idea how should I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the libraries and their paths are not specified this way for g++. Normally the g++ command line should be something like this:

```
g++ -o build/linux2/normal/mongo/mongod ........ -Lsomapath1 -Lsomepath2 -llib1.a -llib2.a  -lpthread -lrt
```

This can be achieved in SCons with a SConscript build script like the following:

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(LIBPATH=['somepath1', 'somepath2'])
env.Append(LIBS=['1', '2', 'pthread', 'rt'])
env.Program(target='build/linux2/normal/mongo/mongod', source='yourSourceFiles')
```

Notice that for the libs and lib paths, you dont need to specify the '-L' nor the '-l'. Also, you dont need to specify the library prefix, nor suffix, hence the lib names are '1' and '2'.

Comment: I have tried this way, but the thing is that using shared objects, I always get an error indicating the linker cannot make proper linking between two shared objects. However, when I use static linking, using .a files, everything is fine. I am looking for a way to do so for mongod in the build script.